# Can a date object be used for sorting an array in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

I have an array of strings containing event dates and names and want to sort them by the date.  The date, however, is buried in the string.  As the date is also an element in itself, as a date object, I have the following code - using date.js

```
arrayEvents.push ({date:myDate, data:mydata});
//once I have all the events pushed on
arrayEvents.sort(function(a,b) {return a.date > b.date});
```

In IE 10 debug I have confirmed that myDate is a object(date), and mydata is a string

The data is coming in in descending order but I want it in ascending order.
Chrome and FF both return ascending order, IE either sorts in descending or does nothing but the result is descending order.

myDate was the result of myDate = new Date(ISODate)  as the ISODate is what I have as input and debug tells me it looks something like  Thu Jun 20 18:00:00 EDT 2013    Type Object. (Date)
however, below it is [prototype] value Invalid Date

As I have had multiple problems understanding Date and needed to manipulate it for different output I do have it available as a string but when I tried

```
arrayEvents.push(data:myDateString, data: mydata)
```

mydata seemed to overwrite myDateString rather than giving me an array with 2 strings in each.

I don't know what else to try.  Sure hope someone can help me out.

Comment: within sort function try `return a.date.getTime() > b.date.getTime()`

Answer (score 3):

> arrayEvents.sort(function(a,b) {return a.date > b.date});

A sort should return 0 or a number greater or less than 0, not a boolean.

```
arrayEvents.sort(function(a,b) {return a.date-b.date});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  the a.date - b.date (instead of '>') did the trick.